# Bootstrap image positioning on top of background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT: I've added an example fiddle here: http://www.bootply.com/xhBIV2zSig - The two black pins should stay above the two houses in the middle when the browser is resizing.

I'm building a website with Bootstrap on which I have a background image with some buildings like so:

```
body {
  background: url(../img/backgroundLarge.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  /* -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; */
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}
```

The background image is "getting cut" while I resize the browser window causing no scrolls which is the kind of effect I am trying to get.

I also have some pins over some of the buildings and I would like them to resize with the background image (keep the same position).

Any idea how to do that?

here's an image to explain things:
[image: Image positioning on top of background]

Basically I want the red pins to stay in the same place on the background as it's resized.

Can this be done by CSS and or JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: are the red pins separate from the image ?

Comment: I don't want to resize the pins, I just want them to be positioned on the same place on top of the background image as the browser is resized

Comment: @Sekai yes, there are separate

Comment: the red pins have position relative or absolute ?

Comment: @Sekai I've tried with both relative and absolute, maybe I'm not using them correctly. In my opinion, if I could just have the background stay the same size and just cut from it so to say as the browser is resizing there won't be any problem

Comment: you will have to reposition the image again with some breakpoints because even with fixed position the building will go out of viewport depending on device dimensions. You can have 3 breakpoints for desktop, tablet and phone respectively.

Comment: When you use `position: relative` it positions it relative to the closest parent that is not `position: static` All elements are static by default, so you will need to change the positioning of your image, then the pins will be positioned relatively to it, assuming that they are inside the div that has the image in the background.

Comment: @TheWaxMann the background is defined in body {} in css. I've updated the first post with a fiddle example

Answer (score 1):

Try Fiddle: [FullscreenBVackwithPins](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/32BF7/)

html

---

```
    <body>
    <div class="pin pin1"></div>
    <div class="pin pin2"></div>
    <div class="pin pin3"></div>
    </body>
```

css

---

```
    body {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFkKU.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    top: 0;
  left: 0;
    position:relative;
}

.pin{
    position:absolute;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    background:#FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:all 1s ease;
    border:1px solid #f00;
}
.pin:hover{
    background:#F00;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}

.pin1{
    left:50%;
}

.pin2{
    left:20%;
}

.pin3{
    left:90%;
}
```

JavaScript

---

```
 $(function() {
  h = $(window).height();
  w = $(window).width();
  $(body).style('background','url(phpthumb.php?src=bg.jpg&w='+w+'&h='+h);
});
```

Comment: Going to try this now

Comment: This doesnt seem to work. It actually stops my background image from getting full screen

Comment: create fiddle if you know! i need more code reference! red pins will be absolute positioned!

Comment: wait i am making demo fiddle for pins with background image

Comment: Updated first post with a fiddle example

Comment: It's pretty close exccept the background is stretching and not keeping it's proporions...

Comment: now its close give me up and i will make it perfect for you for sure! now whats the next step?

Comment: use instead size:100% -webkit-background-size: cover;